# C++: Creating Web Services

Tags: c++, rest, web-services, visual-c++

This is a design suggestion I would like to have from the C++ Web Service experts here.

I'm working on a C++ Windows DLL that currently is used by a exe. The plan is to create a Web Service and expose the functions in the DLL to the web.

From what I researched so far, I came across some libraries that will enable a C++ application to access REST APIs. Buy in my case, Am looking to create a Web Service that will expose the functions in the C++ DLL.

Am looking for something that doesn't involve too much learning curve and can be implemented easily.

Some of the C++ functions currently take vectors as inputs and return a huge vector.

So the capability to input and output large amounts of data is needed. i.e., the exposed Web Service functions should be able to have vectors as arguments passed to it.

Hope to get some valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would recommend WCF web service if it's a windows DLL. You can always call C++ functions from C# code.

A simple WCF API will look something like this

```
[OperationContract]  
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Test/{name}")]  
string Test(string name);
```

In the *.svc.cs file the implementation goes

```
public string Test(string name) 
{  
            return "Hello " + name;  
}
```

And to call C++ functions use the **dllimport**.

Let me know if you need any further help.